# Find optimal set of items

Tags: algorithm

Please, help in resolving the following coding task (no exact code is required, just need a tip how to resolve the problem).

You have a truck and you need to transfer goods using this truck. Each good has a weight (in kg), a time required for loading the good in the truck (in minutes) and a worth. Each good can be loaded in truck only once. There is an example of the available goods (ID, weight, time, worth)

```
0,82,10,300
1,99,22,400
2,2,34,650
3,22,5,92
4,33,31,13
5,99,49,59
```

and so on.
The maximum load of the truck is 1000 kg. You have only 60 minutes to load goods into the truck and you need load the maximum worth. The space of the goods is not calculated. You need to find IDs of goods which should be loaded into the truck.

What approach should I use?

Comment: similar to knapsack problem.

Comment: can be solved with dynamic programming dp[i][j] = max worth you can get with i kg and j minutes

Answer (score 0):

> **Warning:** before you continue reading, I'm not 100% sure this will always return the
>   correct results. But at least on the 3 test I ran it seemed to work
>   right. This is more of an approximation to optimal result, rather than an actual algorithm that is irefutable.

I stored my data in excel, because i found it to be the easiest to display the data / steps I'm working with and also because excel already has some inbuilt functions such as `AVERAGE` and `RANK` so hurray, less coding for me! *(and in general, excel is well equipped for these sort of tasks)*

1. I first started with your original data range

[image]

1. We then calculate the `Worth / Time` & `Worth / Weight` coefficients.
2. Afterwards we calculate the "Likelyhood" of something being shipped, which is an `AVERAGE` of the two before calculated coefficients ^

   [image]
3. Afterwards, we `RANK` each Item in these 3 categories. Where 1 is the highest rank (highest value in the column) and 6 is the lowest rank (lowest value in the column) - this is an equivalent to a sorting algorhitm in programming, for example `quicksort()` is what could be used, if you don't have the rank excel function at your disposal.

   [image]
4. We do one more `AVERAGE` of  all the Individual Rankings we did (so average of timed rank, weight rank &  likelyhood rank)
5. We `RANK` (or in programming terms `quicksort()`) the total averages we created one last time

   [image]
6. **Now we can begin with the actual algorhitm...** We `array.push()` the sorted item-list into an array (indexed by their Total Rank from best (1) to worst (6).
7. We iterate throughout the `array.length` - would look something like `for (i=0; i <= array.length; i++)`
8. We add the individual ranked items to our list. We have two `IF` statements, where we `Continue` the loop (skipping the item) if we either `exceed 100kg OR exceeds 60min`
9. if it's fine (the if conditions don't trigger), add our item to a stack of saved items
10. Loop (until we loop through all the items in our array).

---

Now now, I get it. That's a lot of steps and it sound really confusing when you read it like this. Here it is visualized, where items marked RED is where the if condition triggers. I feel like it helps the visualization a lot.

So with the table of our original data:

[image]

We do the following, step by step

[image]

---

The other Data Ranges I tested on:

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

> There probably are other simpler ways to achieve this, but at least I
>   couldn't think of one and this seems to be working. Hopefully this works for you!

Comment: Minor editing hint: Please don't use quote-blocks if you don't actually quote but just want to highlight. That may be displayed wrong on different user styles. Please use other highlighting tools instead.

Comment: @Zabuza noted, though what other highlighting styles are there? StackOverflow is fairly limited of what you're allowed to insert with html .

Comment: Thanks for great explanation! You've suggested "greedy" algorithm for two units of measure. But for my understanding it should be little bit improved because Likelyhood coefficient can be improperly calculated due to problem with input data. For example, the dataset may have a majority of lightweight items. In this case, several iterations could be done with multiple coefficient (for column worth/weight or for column worth/time) in order to find the best answer.

Answer (score -1):

Considering you want to get the maximum worth loaded into the truck, I would order the items in a vector judging by their ( worth / ( time * weigth ) ) factor and pick the elements from the top of the vector, judging by the factor stated above, while also trying to fulfill the truck to its maximum capacity in the given time.

Comment: This does not work. Consider (10 worth, 1 time, 6 weight) (6 worth, 1 time, 5 weight), (6 worth, 1 time, 5 weight) and a 10 weight limit